# Starting a function in the onCreate (without a button click)?

Tags: android, oncreate

I know this might be a basic question, but I am a beginner and I haven't been able to find an answer.

I would like to know, if it is possible to trigger some function/action while creating an activity. eg. trigger a void without user intervention, start an animation automatically after an Activity is created etc.(at the moment I am trying to trigger an animation without a button click, but this question is general and not specific code related).

I know how to bind an action to a button click and every resource I have found is doing that, I haven't, however, been able to start an animation or a void without it and I am not sure if it is possible. (I have tried using Handler, it worked but prevented the rest of the code being executed - I might have done it wrong, though as I really am a beginner)

so my question(s): Is it possible to trigger a function/animation without user intervention(click)?

If so, where can I find some resources to read about it? (I tried reading Android documentation already)

Thank you very much and I apologize if the question is too simple, I know it might be.

Comment: *`Is it possible to trigger a function/animation without user intervention(click)`* yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this photo. [image]

It clearly explains the [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) of Android activity.

To answer your question, yes, it is possible to trigger a function/animation without user intervention(click). You have to call the function from `onStart()` activity.